# How to use the filter selection as a text header in another cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a header cell based on the results of a filter applied to a column. For example I have a filter that lists results based on name. I am trying to pull a unique list or the filter selection and display the result in another cell:

Example:

Column G Filter Results: (selecting only Doe, John and Smith, Jane from multiple choices)

Doe, John
Doe, John
Smith, Jane
Doe, John
Smith, Jane

What I want to do is to display a unique result in Column A1 of:
Doe, John: Smith, Jane

Simply referencing the filter selection as a text literal would make the most sense, but I have no idea how to reference that in Excel

I am using Excel 2007

Comment: if your *really* need the column header to be the filter choices, you'll probably need a VBA procedure for that.

Comment: Is this a big ask? I was hoping there was a variable/array that is assigned from the filter selection.

Comment: I wouldn't say a big ask, but I don't know of anyway that Excel will automatically assign a variable / array to a filter selection. You may be able create it though, by looping through the items in the filter selection and finding those that are `Visible`. I know this works with PivotTable filters, but I have never tried with just a standard filter... At worse, you can loop through the visible cells once there filtered and build an string that way.